# Why is Unity UI Image color not being animated?

Tags: unity, animation

Animation is changing the color of an UI Image but the color only changes only in the inspector but not Game/Scene view.

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIRDTBrBWFM&feature=youtu.be) video I demonstrate the problem clearly.

Comment: Without seeing your code we can't help you.  Best-guess is that the material used to render the UI image ignores the color.  If you manipulate it in the inspector, not during run-time, do you get the desired effect?

Comment: I don't think you need the code for this one. In the code I simply run the Play on the animation with the animation name.
As for manipulating the color manually,  it works both run-time and not run-time.
As for the material, I use none.

Comment: GUI images still have a material and shader, even if its hidden in a black box.  I do not know what is wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `Material` on the `Image` to something that has the "Sprites-Default" shader so it can react to the changes in the color.

If you don't have the `Material` you need, here's a quick way to create one that would work for what you're trying to do: [Simple Sprite Material Creation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html).  Under "*Shader*" just select "*Sprites* > *Default*".